# React-Data-Table-Component Hide Show Column Base On Conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-data-table-component

I was writing a reactjs code and I use react-data-table-component, my table showed perfectly but  i wanted to hide/show a column base on condition if true or false but I do not know where to write my javascript/typescript expression for the condition to determine if the column will be show or not. See below the basic code to display record in react-data-table-component:

```
//building the columns header
const columns = [
    {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: row => row.title,
    },
    {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: row => row.year,
    },
 {
      /*How do i write javascript conditional code here to determine if this column will be shown or not */
        name: 'Salary',
        selector: row => row.year,
        
    },
];

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Beetlejuice',
        year: '1988',
        salary: '5000'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Ghostbusters',
        year: '1984',
        salary: '5000'
    },
]

function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <DataTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
        />
    );
};
```

My challenge is how/where do I write code to display or hide the column because all efforts to write the javascript/typescript in the column object didn't work. Note that I was able to manipulate or change record at row level using the conditional-row approach but it is the entire column i want to hide/show should a condition is met or not.

Thank you fams.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically omit a column using "omit" prop as shown in the [documentation](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/columns-omit-dynamically--omit-dynamically)

For example:

```
<DataTable
            columns={[
                {
                    name: "ID",
                    selector: row => row.id,
                },
                {
                    name: "Other Data",
                    selector: row => row.otherData,
                    omit: hideData === true
                }
            ]}
            data={data}
        />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a separate column, or writing a `column` object builder? You can append the `column` you want depending on your condition, and set that build to the `columns` object your table uses.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).